# Root disk mbr and non-root gpt

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, gpt, mbr

I have an ec2 instance on aws running linux, with a root volume and another volume for data.
Both are ext4.
I need to increase the data volume size to more than 2 TB.
However currently the partitioning scheme is mbr, so I'm unable to create such partition.
I found that gpt allows more than 2 TB partitions.
But most google search results are not very clear whether same server can have 1 disk ( root ) with mbr and another non-root disk as gpt.

Is this possible and safe in production ?
Anyone has done such kind of setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have one disk with MBR and one with GPT, this is not a problem. You can't have both on the same disk though.